# Is it possible to create a tap based on the location of the taps?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a program in which when I tap in roughly the same location as where my last touch ended, a circle changes color. I've tried using the previousLocationInView method using logic along the lines of: "if touchesbegan location == previousTouchesLocation, change color to blue."  This method didn't work because the touchesBegan and previousTouchLocation coordinates have the same value which always changed the color whenever I tapped the screen regardless of the location. I get the same result if I substitute previousTouchLocation with touchesEnded. Here is the code if anyone thinks that it could help.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastTouchLocation = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];
    distance_x = touchLocation.x - cvx;
    distance_y = cvy - touchLocation.y;
    previousDistance_x = lastTouchLocation.x - cvx;
    previousDistance_y = cvy - lastTouchLocation.y;

    if ((previousDistance_x == distance_x) && (previousDistance_y == distance_y)) {
        if (([cv.color isEqual:[UIColor redColor]])) {
           [cv setColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        }
        else
            [cv setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-previousLocationInView:` gives you the previous location of a touch that's currently moving on the screen. It doesn't give you the location of a different, now ended, touch.

What you're going to have to do is, on the first touch, store the touch's location in a property or ivar. Then, on the second touch, compare its location to the stored location. You'll need to allow for some leeway—fingers are not pixel-accurate in the way mice can be—so a touch that's moved ten or twenty pixels should probably count as a double-tap.

Actually, come to think of it, your best bet might be to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTapsRequired` set to 2. This will handle all the detection logic for you, and you can combine it with other gesture recognizers to build up more complex behaviors.

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed. I followed your advice (created an ivar), and now my program works precisely the way I want it to!